# Image-based flair doesn't include diamond

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair, moderators

I think this was done unintentionally, but I tagged it [feature-request]. The new [even flairier](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) image-based flair doesn't include a ♦ if the user is a mod, but the old version did.

HTML version:
[image: Screenshot of Jeff's HTML flair page]

PNG version:
[image: Jeff's PNG flair]

---

The combined flair doesn't show a ♦ either, but since that didn't exist before it's not really a "change". If you want to keep it consistent, it could show a count like the Area 51 proposer's box does:

[image: Jeff's Area 51 proposer box]

Comment: Lol, Jeff's avatar is like "OMG THERE'S NO DIAMOND!!!"

Comment: DIAMOND OVERFLOW

Comment: @radp The combined flair should just show a diamond for every site you're a mod on; none of this "♦ 30" nonsense. "Jeff Atwood ♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦"

Comment: This question makes no sense now that it's been fixed. I was looking at the screenshots and was like "Wuh? It's right there!!!" Took mea  good minute to figure out what had happened. I need another coffee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just noticed this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now:

[image: Jeff's flair]

Comment: @Steven If you have an observation about a 6 year old bug report, either leave it as a comment, or file it as a new bug report. Don't edit it in to other people's answers.

Comment: It's worth noting that this change does ***not*** apply to [combined user flairs](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1.png).

Comment: @JasonC The question specifically mentioned combined network flairs, so I mistakenly thought it was worth adding. Apologies.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's 7 years old with 266 views. *Nothing* is worth noting here.