# Moderator user flair is missing the diamond

Tags: bug, flair, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image-based flair doesn't include diamond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65773/image-based-flair-doesnt-include-diamond)

To be honest, I didn't notice if the diamonds disappeared when image-based flair was introduced, but since the diamonds were there with the html flair, this seems like a bug now.

Snapshot:

[image]

Live flair to see if/when it's fixed:

[image]

Comment: I'm almost sure this was reported and closed as status-bydesign, but maybe it was just in chat or something.

Comment: AH CRAP. Close as dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65773/image-based-flair-doesnt-include-diamond -- why is that a feature request? @Michael

Comment: Hmm. No status-anything. But it still seems to me that I remember Jeff declining it.

Comment: I figured it had a better chance as a [feature-request] than a [bug] :)